# Increase Height of QPushButton in PyQT

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I have 2 `QPushButton` in the app window: `btn1` needs to be 5x the height of `btn2`.

**Problem:** Tried setting the row span of `self.btn1` to `5` using `layout.addWidget` but the height remains unchanged. did I miss out on a setting?

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()

        self.btn1 = QtGui.QPushButton('Hello')
        self.btn2 = QtGui.QPushButton('World')

        layout.addWidget(self.btn1, 1, 1, 5, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn2, 6, 1, 1, 1)

        centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        centralWidget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: Looking at your code it seems that the first 5 rows must have a very small height. You could try setting a minimum height for each row using `setRowMinimumHeight (self, int row, int minSize)`.

Comment: Do you want the height of the button to be 5 times larger? Like self.btn1.setMinimumHeight(5*self.btn2.height())?

Answer (score 10):

You'll need to change the buttons' size policy:

```
self.btn1.setSizePolicy(
    QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred,
    QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)

self.btn2.setSizePolicy(
    QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred,
    QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
```

From [Qt doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop), by default:

> Button-like widgets set the size policy to specify that they may
>   stretch horizontally, but are fixed vertically.

i.e. The default size policy of `QPushButton` is `Minimum` horizontally, and `Fixed` vertically.

In addition, a simpler way to achieve what you want in the example is to use a `QVBoxLayout`, and set the stretch factor when calling [addWidget()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qboxlayout.html#addWidget). i.e.

```
def initUI(self):
    layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

    self.btn1 = QtGui.QPushButton('Hello')
    self.btn2 = QtGui.QPushButton('World')

    self.btn1.setSizePolicy(
        QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred,
        QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)

    self.btn2.setSizePolicy(
        QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred,
        QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred)

    layout.addWidget(self.btn1, 5)
    layout.addWidget(self.btn2, 1)

    centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
    centralWidget.setLayout(layout)
    self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
```

Comment: cannot import name 'QSizePolicy' from 'PyQt5.QtGui'

Comment: @pf12345678910 in PyQt5, you need `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QSizePolicy`